# DLL Creation for 64 Bit & 32 Bit Environment

Tags: c#, dll

I want to create a DLL (using C#) for the following platforms.

1. 32 bit Machine & 32 Bit OS
2. 64 bit Machine & 32 Bit OS
3. 64 Bit Machine & 64 Bit OS

in this case what should be the platform target as I'm using Visual Studio 2008.

kindly reply.

Comment: Sound like a jolly good set of requirements. You can do it!

Answer (score 1):

Unless you use platform invokes to specific Win32 API functions, COM or third-party compiled code, the `Any CPU` target is fine.

In .NET, target platform doesn't change the compiled intermediate language but it's just a constraint to limit where to execute your libraries and executables.

For example, if you compile in `Debug|x64` then your code won't be executable in 32bit operating systems.

In summary: compile in `Debug|AnyCPU`, `Release|AnyCPU` and your software will work in any OS and CPU architecture with the exception of accessing native code from C# (i.e. `[DllImport]`), where you'll need to be sure that native code is accessed from a process of 32 or 64bit depending on the native code's target platform.

Comment: Created dll is working fine in 32 bit OS on 32 bit Machine. But the following error message I've received while trying the same in 64 Bit OS on 64 Bit Machine.

**A call to System.__ComObject.DetectCardReader failed with this message: Unable to load DLL 'ACR120U.DLL': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)**

Comment: @user724817 So you enter in the exception part of my answer. Then you need to compile in `Debug|x86` and `Debug|x64` and be sure that the COM object is available for both 32 and 64bit processes

Comment: We'll create two different dll for from Debug|x86 and Debug|x64 ??

Comment: @user724817 Yes, but again, you need to be sure that the COM object you're accessing can be used from a 64bit process

Comment: The same error message is coming after creating the dll from Debug|x64

Comment: @user724817 I told you that maybe your COM component doesn't support 64bit architecture.......

Comment: @user724817 If this is the case.. then compile in Debug|x86 only, and it should work in 64bit OSes using Windows on Windows 64 (an abstraction layer part of default Windows 64bit installations...)

Comment: Actually I want to integrate an ACR Card Reader Machine with my ERP Package (Microsoft ERP Software).

Comment: @user724817 Ask another question with more details about your concrete issue. I believe your current Q&A is already answered in the format you composed it

Comment: Actually I want to integrate an ACR Card Reader Machine with my ERP Package (Microsoft ERP Software). The Card Reader has two different drivers for two differents platform(32 bit & 64 bit)
The drivers has many dll & two of them are as follows..
1. acr120u.dll
2. acr120ux64.dll

Comment: The ERP Programming Language (C/AL) is not able to direct access the above mentioned dlls. That’s why I’ve created a proxy dll and then add a ACR120U.cs ( provided by ACR) class in my project (Class Library) called CSClb (using C#, VS 2008). In this project I’ve written few functions/Methods in cobmination of ACR120U class.
Dll created from the project CSClb working fine( Registered by RegAsm.Exe) in 32 bit machine. But it’s not working in 64 bit Machine.

Comment: @user724817 I can't understand your problem. Summarize it and ask another question (not a comment!!)

Comment: Problem Solved. Thank you.

Comment: @user724817 I'm glad you managed to get the right solution. You're welcome ;)